# Chef: how to store only attributes for explicitly included recipes

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm fixing a cookbook for redis, with 2 distinct recipes + a default one.
On the default recipe I add the a PPA repository and do the apt-get update stuff.
What I would like to do is be able to persist on the node, only the attributes for the corresponding enabled recipes:

If the node includes "server" recipe, then store the defaults from attributes/server.rb
If the node includes "client" recipe, then store the defaults from attributes/client.rb

The documentation isn't clear enough to whether the above will happen or it will store both, despite the recipes inclusion.

What i've seen people suggesting is to move the node.default[...] definitions that are specific to a recipe only and does not fit on "default" recipe to the recipe itself. I believe that this is non logical.

What is the "best-practice" to achieve this separation?

Comment: That's the typical best practice. You can use something like https://github.com/poise/poise-appenv otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The key quote [from Chef's documentation](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_attribute_files.html) is: "When a cookbook is run against a node, the attributes contained in ***all*** attribute files are evaluated in the context of the node object." (emphasis mine). You can only achieve what you're talking about by moving to using node.(scope) in the recipes.

Comment: I've read that, but "evaluated" is different from "persisted". What I was thinking that could be sane is that it should load all attributes but persist only if the corresponding recipe was either on run_list or included from another recipe.

Answer (score 0):

For thing you need in the client recipe

`node[:redis][:client][:foo] = "bar"`

For things you need in the server recipe

`node[:redis][:server][:foo] = "bar"`

Out of curiosity, which redis recipe are you using?

Comment: this is my fork: https://github.com/brodock/chef-redis, i had to updated it because the ppa it depends on doesn't compile "redis-doc" anymore, and also I wasn't able to install redis-client on a machine without installing the server before.